# sql query that produce the following result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

> can anyone tell me the sql query(MySQL) that will result following output from the table .

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of pivot?

Comment: Which is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: Date 30/2/2013?? In which year February had 30 days??

Comment: Perhaps Rahul is on another planet ;-)

Comment: Edit your question please and I will upvote as it is indeed interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You're after a PIVOT TABLE QUERY - although it's often better to perform the basic aggregation in (My)SQL and then handle problems of display at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP).

A standard query might look as follows, although MySQL supports shorthand deviations from this standard...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M') month
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Rahul' THEN value END),0) Rahul 
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Vijay' THEN value END),0) Vijay
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Loki' THEN value END),0) Loki
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY MONTH(date);
```

Comment: GROUP BY should maybe include YEAR(date) or this may fail to work at some time.

Comment: That was deliberate. I thought the OP wanted to compare month-by-month performance across all years - but I certainly could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH w AS (
  SELECT 10 AS value, 'Rahul' AS status, TO_DATE('20/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date_time FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 'Vijay', TO_DATE('28/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 'Loki', TO_DATE('03/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 25, 'Kiran', TO_DATE('05/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Rahul', TO_DATE('02/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 'Vijay', TO_DATE('10/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 08, 'Loki', TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
)
  SELECT TO_CHAR(date_time, 'Mon') AS m
         , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Rahul' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Rahul
         , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Vijay' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Vijay
         , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Loki' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Loki
         , SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Kiran' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Kiran
         , SUM(value) AS Total
    FROM w
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date_time, 'Mon')
ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_time, 'Mon'), 'Mon')
;
```